# .net: XLS->ODBC->DataTable - why doesn't it just work?

Tags: .net, excel, datatable, odbc

I have build a small sample to test XLS-imports and am having problems.

**Sample Data**

If you trust me, the download is [here](http://mbaas.de/footable.zip)
A really simple sheet, it looks like this:[image]

- Column **B** is a manually entered date
- Column **C** is a formula to calculate the age: `=YEARFRAC(B2;TODAY())`
- Column **F**: `=10*roundup(C2/10;0)`

*that should be enough for a repro*

So, in any .net-language of your choice *(I'm using [APL](http://dyalog.com) but will spare you the details*):

- use the libraries 'System.Data.Odbc,System.Data.dll'  'System.Data,system.data.dll'
- initialize `dt`as a new DataTable-object
- assign `d`as new `OdbcDataAdapter(  'SELECT * FROM [Tabelle1$]'  'Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};DBQ={Filename.xlsx};')`
- and finally do `d.Fill(dt)`
- then look at the first record.

Here's what I did and got:

```
     dt.Rows[0].ItemArray

┌───┬───────────────────┬───────────────────────────────────────────────┬─┬─┬─┬───────────────────┐    
│foo│13.03.1966 00:00:00│Die Eingabezeichenfolge hat das falsche Format.│0│0│0│13.03.1966 00:00:00│    
└───┴───────────────────┴───────────────────────────────────────────────┴─┴─┴─┴───────────────────┘
```

You see the 3d cell has an error-message instead of the age-calculation, the 5th cell is 0 instead of 60 and even worse: the calculation in G is not done - w/o any indication of there being a problem! Now, on one occasion I happened to have the sheet open in Excel while I went through this steps - and then I got correct results:

```
┌───┬───────────────────┬──────┬─┬─┬──┬───────────────────┐
│foo│13.03.1966 00:00:00│51.925│0│0│60│13.03.2026 00:00:00│
└───┴───────────────────┴──────┴─┴─┴──┴───────────────────┘
```

So, it is possible to have this working right!

A coworker tried to open the sheet on his machine and had to confirm a message about macros - and he claims it then worked right.

Well, is there a way to get this working w/o requiring people to open the sheet in Excel or fiddle with any of their settings?